# How to tell if a given cell is in an array range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Some formulas (ARRAYFORMULA, QUERY) can yield values that "spill over" into neighboring cells, as described here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en.

When you select the cell where the array-valued formula is specified, you can see the formula definition. However, if you select cells that were "spilled into", you only see its calculated value.

Is there a way to tell that a cells value is being governed by a "neighboring" formula?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

To quickly find if a cell is filled by an array formula or an array expression, select the cell and press **Delete**. If the value in the cell disappears completely, it is *not* filled by an array formula. You can then choose **Edit > Undo** to restore the value in the cell.

If the value gets erased for a second, but then almost immediately gets restored, there must be an array formula to the left or up of the cell that fills it.

If the cell you are interested in is blank to start with, insert the character `a` in the cell. That will cause any array formula to the left or up of the cell to show a `#REF` error. Delete the `a` to re-enable the array formula.